# How can detect the count of page fault on windows OS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, memory

How can detect the count of page fault on windows 2008 or windows 7?
in the next process is it possible detect the best RAM for system (system is dedicated server on the web)?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the page fault count per process directly on the Task Manager, by enabling the appropriate column. But let me tell you a secret: "page fault", "swapping" and "RAM shortage" are only vaguely related subjects, and a high page fault count can not only be perfectly fine, but means *absolutely nothing* on its own.

About the best RAM for your system... the more, the better. There really is no such thing as too much RAM.

Comment: Agreed, RAM is insanely cheap at the moment, so the more the better.